# Erlang Client for XMPP server

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, ejabberd-api, exmpp

Is there any good Erlang client for XMPP server. I checked exmpp but it is too old and not compiling.
Any pointers would be good. I have to send and receive a message both. The Ejabberd REST API will not fit here, as I need to get message back as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use escalus xmpp library from https://github.com/esl/escalus.

Comment: tried using escalus, but it does not work as expected

Comment: Are you getting any error while compiling or running escalus ?

Comment: yes, I changed the localhost to my domain in the config file and it seems not to parse it.

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/processone/exmpp/releases  go here download the latest  release.
Extract it.
Make sure you have all neccesary things installed like libtools and erlang.
In the extracted directory run :

```
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

By default this will install exmpp to your erlang environment library. You can specify a custom directory by:

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/install/exmpp/here
```

You can find example code in the "examples" directory. Go through them for better understanding.